# Handling JSON user input in a Django Form

Tags: python, html, django

This is a part of a school assigment where we have to use a JSON field in a model for our simple Django project. In this "book club" website, the user must have the ability to submit new books to the server. I would like the user input to not require knowing JSON syntax.

The model for the book is as follows:

```
class Book(models.Model):

    #book information
    name = models.CharField(default='title', max_length=100) #Name of the book
    authors = models.JSONField() #Author of the book
    year_published = models.IntegerField() #Year the book was published in 
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) #Date added (automatic)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) #Date modified (automatic)

    def __str__(self): #Return the full title of the book with its author and publish year.
        fullname = f"{self.authors}.{self.name};({self.year_published})"
        return fullname
```

I'm concerned about the 'authors' field in this case.

Now the form into which the user would submit new books:

```
class AddBook(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = "__all__"
```

[image: Looks something like this:]

And the view for add book functionality:

```
def addbook(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        #no data submitted
        form = AddBook()

    else:
        form = AddBook(data=request.POST)
        print(form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('cbc:books')
        
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'cbc/addbook.html', context)
```

Now, this all works, but since the "authors" field in in JSON, it is extremely unintuitive to type the book author in JSON like "John Smith" quotes included, otherwise the form isn't valid.

What would be a good way to handle this kind of input?

Comment: What's wrong with `CharField`, say comma or semicolon separated? Or a `TextField`, with authors on different lines?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that this is bad design since `authors` should be a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) linked to another model `Author` that holds the name to avoid duplicates.

---

To keep in your path, we need a preprocess function that will "JSONify" the input. We call here `input_authors_preprocess()`. Here, as an example, we want the user to write `John,Bob` without quotes.

```python
def input_authors_preprocess(input_authors):
    result = "["
    input_authors = input_authors.replace('"','')
    l_authors = input_authors.split(',')
    if len(l_authors) == 1:
        result += '"' + l_authors[0] + '"'
    elif len(l_authors) > 1:
        for author in l_authors[:-1]:
            result += '"' + author + '",'
        result += '"' + l_authors[-1] + '"'
    result += "]"
    return result
```

Then we change the view to use our preprocess function :

```python
def addbook(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        #no data submitted
        form = AddBook()

    else:
        form = AddBook(data=request.POST)
        data_copy = form.data.copy()
        data_copy['authors'] = input_authors_preprocess(data_copy['authors'])
        form.data = data_copy
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('cbc:books')
        else:
            form.data = request.POST
        
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'cbc/addbook.html', context)
```